# How to check if number lies within many ranges?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, if-statement

I have a list of numbers `from 1 to 24`

```
hour = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

I want to create four separate lists `(a, b, c, d)` based on respective conditions:

```
a = (22<= number <6)
b = (6<= number <9 or 12<= number <18)
c = (9<= number <12)
d = (18<= number <22
```

if condition is `True` then 1 `else` 0

### Expected output:

[image]

---

I can create the `a` column but with rest of them I am facing issue,

### My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('mask.xlsx')
hour = df['Hours']
df['a'] = [1 if i>=22 or i<6 else 0 for i in hour]
b=[]
for i,j in zip(hour, df['a']):
    if i <= 6 and i < 9:
        if i<=12 and i<18:
            if j==0:
                b.append(1)
    else:
        b.append(0)
df['b'] = b
```

### Error I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: Condition b makes no sense -- how can a number be in the range 6-9 and 12-18 at the same time?  Did you mean "or" instead of "and"?

Comment: ```&&``` is logical AND. ```b = (6<= number <9 && 12<= number <18)```. This condition is always False

Comment: sorry, or is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.select` implement if-elif-else logic to assign the group and then form the dummies from that Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

conds = [df['Hours'].lt(6) | df['Hours'].ge(22),
         (df['Hours'].ge(6) & df['Hours'].lt(9)) | (df['Hours'].ge(12) & df['Hours'].lt(18)),
         df['Hours'].ge(9) & df['Hours'].lt(12),
         df['Hours'].ge(18) & df['Hours'].lt(22)        
        ]

choices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

dums = pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(np.select(conds, choices), index=df.index))

df = pd.concat([df, dums], axis=1)
```

---

```
    Hours  a  b  c  d
0       1  1  0  0  0
1       2  1  0  0  0
2       3  1  0  0  0
3       4  1  0  0  0
4       5  1  0  0  0
5       6  0  1  0  0
6       7  0  1  0  0
7       8  0  1  0  0
8       9  0  0  1  0
9      10  0  0  1  0
10     11  0  0  1  0
11     12  0  1  0  0
12     13  0  1  0  0
13     14  0  1  0  0
14     15  0  1  0  0
15     16  0  1  0  0
16     17  0  1  0  0
17     18  0  0  0  1
18     19  0  0  0  1
19     20  0  0  0  1
20     21  0  0  0  1
21     22  1  0  0  0
22     23  1  0  0  0
23     24  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend vectorized comparisons directly with the Series. Also taking advantage of [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and the `inclusive` argument to make loweround inclusive:

```
df['a'] = (df['Hours'].ge(22) | df['Hours'].lt(6)).astype(int)
df['b'] = (df['Hours'].between(6, 9, inclusive='left') |
           df['Hours'].between(12, 18, inclusive='left')).astype(int)
df['c'] = df['Hours'].between(9, 12, inclusive='left').astype(int)
df['d'] = df['Hours'].between(18, 22, inclusive='left').astype(int)
```

Notice: Both compound conditions should be *or* not *and*.

- `a` is Hours more than 22 *or* less than 6.
- `b` are hours between [6, 9) *or* [12, 18).

---

Perhaps a bit overkill here, but can also use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) after [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with duplicate labels then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back:

```
df = df.join(
    pd.get_dummies(
        pd.cut(df['Hours'],
               bins=[1, 6, 9, 12, 18, 22, 25],
               labels=['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a'],
               ordered=False,
               right=False)
    )
)
```

---

Both Options Produce:

`df`:

```
    Hours  a  b  c  d
0       1  1  0  0  0
1       2  1  0  0  0
2       3  1  0  0  0
3       4  1  0  0  0
4       5  1  0  0  0
5       6  0  1  0  0
6       7  0  1  0  0
7       8  0  1  0  0
8       9  0  0  1  0
9      10  0  0  1  0
10     11  0  0  1  0
11     12  0  1  0  0
12     13  0  1  0  0
13     14  0  1  0  0
14     15  0  1  0  0
15     16  0  1  0  0
16     17  0  1  0  0
17     18  0  0  0  1
18     19  0  0  0  1
19     20  0  0  0  1
20     21  0  0  0  1
21     22  1  0  0  0
22     23  1  0  0  0
23     24  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: hey thank you so much man but there is something wrong here, first number in a touple should be <= and second number in touple should le <. for example in a 22 <= number < 6

Comment: That's not how math works though. There is no real number that matches that condition: `22 <= number < 6`. 6 is a smaller number than 22.

Comment: yeah I am sorry for that, i didn't write it correctly but if you look at the expected number for a column, 1 is there when hour is >= 22 and also when hour is < 6

Comment: Yes. And in my `a` column in the posted output there are 1s for 1-5 and 1s for 22-24. No?

Comment: Idk what's wrong but when I try this code, in the B column there is 1 at 9th hour

Answer (score 3):

Using `np.select` and `pd.crosstab`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Hours": hour})

df["g"] = (np.select([(df.Hours<6)|(df.Hours>=22),
                      (df.Hours<12)&(df.Hours>=9),
                      (df.Hours<22)&(df.Hours>=18),],
                     list("acd"), "b"))

print (pd.crosstab(df["Hours"], df["g"]))

g      a  b  c  d
Hours            
1      1  0  0  0
2      1  0  0  0
3      1  0  0  0
4      1  0  0  0
5      1  0  0  0
6      0  1  0  0
7      0  1  0  0
8      0  1  0  0
9      0  0  1  0
10     0  0  1  0
11     0  0  1  0
12     0  1  0  0
13     0  1  0  0
14     0  1  0  0
15     0  1  0  0
16     0  1  0  0
17     0  1  0  0
18     0  0  0  1
19     0  0  0  1
20     0  0  0  1
21     0  0  0  1
22     1  0  0  0
23     1  0  0  0
24     1  0  0  0
```